# android-async-http uploading image to php server

Tags: php, android, android-async-http

I've been looking all day about how to upload image from my application to server side.
I've done the mobile application side

```
public static void postImage(String ImageLink){
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("uploaded_file[name]", "MyImageName");
    try {
        params.put("uploaded_file[image]", new File(ImageLink));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.post(MY_PHP_FILE_LINK, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            System.out.println("statusCode "+statusCode);//statusCode 200
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

        }
    });
}
```

and my php side code

```
<?php

$file_path = "/uploads/";

$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
    echo "success";
} else{
    echo "fail";
}?>
```

but I cant find the image on server even the statusCode was OK

what is the problem?? is my php code wrong?

Comment: show your body plz of your response

Comment: @eddykordo it only show  fail

Comment: maybe you have wrong chmod for your uploads folder

Comment: @eddykordo it set to 775 I've used another method for uploading the image using standard http request and it works, but I want to use the post method of android-sync-http library because I use it in my whole application and its very good

Comment: @eddykordo I've fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've Solved the problem, it was in my RequestParams I've tried to change the file name but it seems I can't do it so that I've change my code and it works fine

```
public static void postImage(String ImageLink){
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
try {
    params.put("uploaded_file", new File(ImageLink));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.post(MY_PHP_FILE_LINK, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
        System.out.println("statusCode "+statusCode);//statusCode 200
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

    }
});
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I have problem with loading image:
413 Request Entity Too Large. Search solve again :)